# What did you prepare for tomorrow's lunch? What you have prepared for tomorrow's lunch?

Tags: grammar

What did you prepare for tomorrow's lunch?
What you have prepared for tomorrow's lunch?

Which sentence is correct? 
Many thanks.

Comment: Please read your second sentence... if that's what you meant, it's the incorrect one. Maybe: "What have you prepared for tomorrow's lunch?"

Comment: "What had you prepared for tomorrow's lunch before you realised that preparing a lunch so far in advance may give us food poisoning?" pehaps. Grammar is one thing, surviving food poisoning another.

Answer (score 1):

Both these sentences are correct

The first is simple past, it asks about a action that happened in the past.

The second is present perfect. It asks about current state resulting from a past action.

You could use either. In the context that you are asking "what will I eat for lunch today" The present perfect would be more natural.  In the context in which you are asking about "what did you do this morning" then use the simple past.

> I'm hungry. Let's eat. What have you prepared for lunch?
>
> How was your day? Did you go shopping? What did you prepare for lunch?